# pull a sub document and just return it's value

Tags: mongodb

i have this cart data in mydb, cart contains array of products :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97a"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc979"),
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "product_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97f"),
            "product_name" : "Cangkir",
            "product_price" : NumberLong(10000),
            "productavatar" : [ 
                "default-product.jpg"
            ],
            "merchant_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97d"),
            "merchant_name" : "Merchant Test 1",
            "quantity" : NumberLong(1),
            "buyer_note" : "Mohon dipacking dengan rapi",
            "updated" : false,
            "message" : ""
        }
    ],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-08-17T10:49:01.692Z"),
    "updated_at" : Timestamp(1597661341, 19)
}
```

i want pull product in cart, and just return the product is pulled.
this is my query :

```
//first
db.getCollection('carts').findOneAndUpdate({"_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97a"), "products.product_id" :ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97f")},{"$pull" : {"products" : { "product_id" :  ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97f")}}},{"projection" : { "products.$" : 1}})

//second
db.getCollection('carts').findOneAndUpdate({"_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97a")},{"$pull" : {"products" : { "product_id" :  ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97f")}}},{"projection" : {"products" : {"$elemMatch" : {"product_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97f")}}}})
```

Result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97a"),
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "product_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97f"),
            "product_name" : "Cangkir",
            "product_price" : NumberLong(10000),
            "productavatar" : [ 
                "default-product.jpg"
            ],
            "merchant_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97d"),
            "merchant_name" : "Merchant Test 1",
            "quantity" : NumberLong(1),
            "buyer_note" : "Mohon dipacking dengan rapi",
            "updated" : false,
            "message" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

this query is work to pull the product but the return value is not single pulled product.
This is what i expected return :

```
{
            "product_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97f"),
            "product_name" : "Cangkir",
            "product_price" : NumberLong(10000),
            "productavatar" : [ 
                "default-product.jpg"
            ],
            "merchant_id" : ObjectId("5f3a609dfb64f953c45bc97d"),
            "merchant_name" : "Merchant Test 1",
            "quantity" : NumberLong(1),
            "buyer_note" : "Mohon dipacking dengan rapi",
            "updated" : false,
            "message" : ""
}
```

is my approach cannot be works? or i must change another approach, i have read about aggregate but i bit more confused to me

Thanks

Comment: no it is not possible, you can not get only one object of array, i think you can access easily after query in form variable using `varName[0]`.

Comment: yeah, i think not bad to make in application level code to achive that. thank's @turivishal